# Creating datastores in GeoServer REST API with external file option

Tags: geoserver, api, rest

Following the REST API documentation [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/datastores.yaml) I should be able to do a PUT request to `/workspaces/{workspaceName}/datastores/{storeName}/{method}.{format}`. Problem is I cannot get how to do it with an `external` method option.

This is with I'm doing:
I already have a `.zip` file with shapefiles in the GeoServer data directory and I do the following PUT:
`/workspaces/MyWorkspace/datastores/StoreName/external.shp`

The file absolute path is in the body and the `myWorkspace` already exists.

Geoserver logs: 

`org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error while storing uploaded file:
...
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "/Users/Projects/geoserver/data/release/myData/shapefile.zip"`

It really seems to me that GeoServer is trying to process the file path as an `URL` but that should only happen if `method` was `URL`.

Also, I'm able to do this request if `method` is `file` and the body has the file binary.

Comment: please add the actual xml messages you are using to the question

Comment: I think your external file should be a shapefile not a zip file for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this on my local machine and the [example from the documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/workspaces.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile)

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain"  \
-d "file:///stuff/ian/geoserver/data/data/shapefiles/states.shp"  \
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/rivers/external.shp
```

works exactly as expected.

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/rivers/external.shp HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 59
> 
* upload completely sent off: 59 out of 59 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 15:53:29 GMT
```

Your body should be a File URL exactly as you would add it to the `Shapefile location` box in the Datastore creation page.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out, it was a problem with my client request library, which by default was sending non-binary request as json type.